# Diagnosing why two Java Threads hanging

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

Trying to make sense of my application hanging, it was all running fine then hung.
I then attached Yourkit Profiler which highlighted two threads that had not changed for some time and appeared to have hang.

The interesting thing is both threads were performing the same task but on different data, however the method is simply a cpu intensive task which isn't sharing data, performing I/O or connecting to anything else.

```
public int[][] computeAssignments(float[][] matrix)
```

So with this in mind I cannot understand what could be causing them to just stop

Both threads are run as part of an an ExecutorService

What approach should I take to resolve this.

**Update**

As Glen guessed the problem turned out to be completely unrelated to threads. It is just that they both happened to hit the same problem, the code they were calling could go into a recursive loop if a particular set of data was provided. A good hint another poster gave was to check in profiler whether the threads were in Runnable or Waiting state, only if they were in waiting state would they actually be deadlocked.

Comment: You realize this is nowhere near enough info to diagnose a problem, right?

Comment: have you tried debugging with the help of any debugging tool?Try it line by line, and you will realize where exactly problem is being caused.

Comment: Does it happen every time? Is it deterministic?

Comment: @Sumit: If it's a deadlock, the very act of attaching a debugger could screw with timing enough to hide the bug.

Comment: lets see the computeAssignments code? Most obvious guess is you've got an infinite loop in there.

Comment: Probably using JConsole or JVisualvm can help, at least they will show you some details about the threads, stack traces and if they are waiting on a lock. Or do a kill -3 on unix to have a look at the thread dump, shows also the locks. Helped me alot of times finding deadlock causes.

Comment: No the problem does not happen every time and is not deterministic, and I've already connected with a profiler (Yourkit Profiler) and have stack traces, but my point was I could see no way how it could deadlock.

Comment: @Glen Lamb , that could be it, never thought of that assumed it was a threading issue, I've added the code

Comment: If it's an infinite loop the thread dump would show all threads in the runnable state.  If it's a deadlock then you'd see two (or more) threads in the blocking state holding onto resources the other wants.  The thread dump should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: They are in a Runnable state, just noticed the calling method does have some code in a whileloop so Im guessing depending on the data sent the algorithm can fail and never leave that loop, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you have an infinite loop there.

Comment: Yep, Ive added some debugging to see paramteers passed to method and invovation of while lopp, but as luck would have it hasn't failed yet after running for 45 minutes

Comment: Hava managed to confirm the code can get stuck in a loop given a particular matrix, and added code to handle this.